# How to properly add a .qrc file to a QT 6 widget app with Cmake as building system?

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying to use a .qrc file to store icon images for my QT application but the Resources.qrc file never appears in resource selection. I'm using CMake as building system and 6.3.1 QT version.

When simply adding Resource.qrc to source files with `AUTORCC ON` file never appears in project tree, when specifically written as project source in CMakeLists it appears in project tree, but never in resource selection when I'm trying to set ToolButton icon, no matter if I add prefix and images or not.

When AUTORCC is OFF and `qt_add_resources(PROJECT_SOURCES Resources.qrc)` added to CMakeLists, Resources.qrc file appears in CMake modules folder in a tree, but again, never in resource selection.

There are a lot of guides about .qrc when QMake is building system, but I hardly found anything about same thing with CMake, and none of them helped me, maybe I couldn't understand them properly. Sorry for possible mistakes, I'm new in programming and english isn't my native language. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi
Do you use QtCreator IDE or something else like clion or vs?

Comment: QT Creator 7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

I just struggled for few hours figuring how to simply import an image in a Qt Quick application. Here's what worked for me.

The images I want to add are located at `/my-project/assets/icon.png` and `/my-project/assets/icon-with-alias.png`.

I created a resource file at the project's root `/my-project/images.qrc` :

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>assets/icon.png</file>
        <file alias="alias.png">assets/icon-with-alias.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

qt_add_executable(your_app_name_here
    main.cpp
    images.qrc
)
```

From nom on, your .qrc file should be visible in the project tree.
Unfortunately I didn't manage to make the image usable with Qt Toolbar for images.
Still, you can use the image by doing in `Main.qml`:

```
Image {
    id: img
    source: "/images/assets/icon.png"
}

Image {
    id: img-with-alias
    source: "/images/alias.png"
}
```

Hope this help a bit.